# Ternary operator syntax error in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

The following is the syntax error that I am experiencing in my blade view:

> syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'

**Code**

```php
{{auth()->user()->role_id==4 ? '<a class="btn-floating mb-1 btn-flat waves-effect waves-light pink accent-2 white-text" href="/update-customer-installement/{{$list->id}}/{{$list->book_id}}"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>':'' }}
```

Comment: You don't need double curly braces when you're already inside a double curly brace, since you're already inside the blade echo syntax. You'd only need single curly braces if you were going more than 1 level down in an object

Comment: use if condition @if(auth()->user()->role_id==4 )
     <a class="btn-floating mb-1 btn-flat waves-effect waves-light pink accent-2 white-text" href="/update-customer-installement/{{$list->id}}/{{$list->book_id}}">
<i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
     
     @endif

Comment: yeah sorry my bad thankyou <3 anyber and john for that idea too

Comment: As a hint: if your code is so unreadable as the one in the example, better avoid such special operators. It's much more readable for you and for other developers to write out a proper loop. Also, having a ternary operator without anything in the "else" part is useless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it simpler:

```
@if(auth()->user()->role_id === 4)
    <a class="btn-floating mb-1 btn-flat waves-effect waves-light pink accent-2 white-text" href="/update-customer-installement/{{ $list->id }}/{{ $list->book_id }}">
        <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
    </a>
@endif
```

Comment: If it works, then you could accept this answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
{{ auth()->user()->role_id==4 ? '<a class="btn-floating mb-1 btn-flat waves-effect waves-light pink accent-2 white-text" href="/update-customer-installement/<?php echo $list->id;?>/<?php echo $list->book_id;?>"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>':'' }}
```

its 100% worked i have tested
i hope you got your solution .